# ! could not find commit hash for master error when using npx in Google Colab

Tags: git, github, google-colaboratory, npx, degit

I'm running the following code on Google Colab:

```
!npx degit cironis/ep4 -f
```

and I'm getting this error message:

```
npx: installed 1 in 0.975s
> destination directory is not empty. Using --force, continuing
! could not find commit hash for master
```

I have used this exact same code with another repository and it worked perfectly. But it does not work with this repository. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has changed its default branch from `master` to `main` instead. But degit still use `master` by default. So, you need to explicitly tell degit to use `main`

```
!npx degit cironis/ep4#main -f
```

This should download it correctly.